# Linking WXWidgets in C++ on Mac OSX 10.7 objects not working

Tags: osx-lion, libraries, c++, g++

For a cross-platform project, we are using wxwidgets to create a cross-platform GUI in c++. WxWidgets was installed on Mac OSX 10.7 using macports. We have no problems with compiling our source-code on Linux and Windows.

Compiling our different classes works fine on Mac. However, when we try to link the objects we get the following errors/warnings:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../obj/games.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../obj/lobby.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../obj/ConfigFile.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file ../../obj/net.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
 ld: warning: ignoring file ../../obj/protocol.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_main", referenced from:
    start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems as gcc can't link the files. When we want to compile and link one file at once, we get a working program. As we now have multiple files, which we want to link, we can't do this at once. We use the following makefile:

https://github.com/timvdalen/OGO-2.3/blob/master/src/lobby/Makefile

Our source code is also included there. I use the following version of gcc:

```
gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Has anyone an idea how we can link these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer myself: you have to compile using `g++ -arch i386`. The linker seems to only want to link in 32-bit mode.